# Using IDataProtectionProvider in test project?

Tags: c#, encryption, asp.net-core, .net-core, integration-testing

When using `IDataProtectionProvider` in a Web API, the IoC container is configured with `AddDataProtection` (`services.AddDataProtection();`) and enables the use of DI to retrieve a `IDataProtectionProvider`in a service as such:

```
private readonly IDataProtectionProvider _dataProtectionProvider;

public CipherService(IDataProtectionProvider dataProtectionProvider)
{
    _dataProtectionProvider = dataProtectionProvider;
}
```

If I would like to test my `CipherService` (in my case using Xunit), I will not be able to make this work without using DI, so my question is;

Q: *How can I use DI or otherwise make `IDataProtectionProvider` in a test project?*

Comment: So why not just mock the dependency and inject it into the dependent class?

Comment: Because this is an integration test.

Comment: Review the [source code](https://github.com/aspnet/DataProtection/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection/DataProtectionServiceCollectionExtensions.cs) and see which dependencies you need to mock/stub/fake

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here how I did it using Moq framework:

```
Mock<IDataProtector> mockDataProtector = new Mock<IDataProtector>();
mockDataProtector.Setup(sut => sut.Protect(It.IsAny<byte[]>())).Returns(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("protectedText"));
mockDataProtector.Setup(sut => sut.Unprotect(It.IsAny<byte[]>())).Returns(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("originalText"));

Mock<IDataProtectionProvider> mockDataProtectionProvider = new Mock<IDataProtectionProvider>();
mockDataProtectionProvider.Setup(s => s.CreateProtector(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(mockDataProtector.Object);
```

And where I need to pass in the IDataProtectionProvider, I use:

```
mockDataProtectionProvider.Object
```

For an integration test scenario, where you want a real DataProtectionProvider, you can use the following [MSDN Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/non-di-scenarios) article.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It does not work if you use extended Protect method that takes a string instead of a byte array, any idea ?

Comment: This does not work for me, because it is a unsported Expression.
(here: DataProtectionCommonExtensions.CreateProtector) may not be used in setup / verification expressions.
Can you explain how you resolved this?

Answer (score 12):

[EphemeralDataProtectionProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/implementation/key-storage-ephemeral?view=aspnetcore-2.1) can be used in a unit testing scenario as it generates a random secret for each instance.

Example:

```
var dataProtectionProvider = new EphemeralDataProtectionProvider();

var service = new CipherService(dataProtectionProvider);

// test as usual
```

This was specifically provided by Microsoft for your exact use-case.

> There are scenarios where an application needs a throwaway IDataProtectionProvider. For example, the developer might just be experimenting in a one-off console application, or the application itself is transient (it's scripted or **a unit test project**). To support these scenarios the Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection package includes a type EphemeralDataProtectionProvider. This type provides a basic implementation of IDataProtectionProvider whose key repository is held solely in-memory and isn't written out to any backing store.

Comment: I believe this should be the accepted answer because it gives a way to protect/unprotect your data in the "arrange / prepare" phase of your test, then apply / test the opposite operation in the test itself.

Anyway, thanks for your help!